# How to get rid of fruit flies on front porch

Tags: pest-control

I think they are fruit flies since they are small. They move at regular speed like a fly but they keep hovering all day on my front porch.

I do have a waterbody (small fountain) there now, but it was dry for 4-5 months when I was fixing it, but the flies were still there.

How do I get rid of them?
Thanks
-Amit

Answer (score 1):

Fruit flies by their name are attracted to fruit and rotting food. So they live and multiply around damp mulch, compost bins, rubbish bins, pastures (with cows) etc.

- For inside you can spray them with flyspray or install insect screens on your doors and windows.
- For the porch, you really need to remove the source.  Look for the spot where the numbers are huge and see if you can get rid of it.  We spray flyspray in our compost bins to control them.

Comment: Websearch will find many DIY fly traps that use vinegar, or occasionally diluted honey, as the attractant. Some commercially sold traps are exactly that in fancier packaging. If the infestation is particular bad, I've been known to spendd an hour cutting down the population by chasing them with a vacuum cleaner. MAKE SURE no other food source is available for them to feed/breed on.

Comment: +1: in my experience this is always the case.  My friend asked "how do I get rid of fruit flies in my kitchen", and I ironically replied "get rid of the rotting fruit!"  He got home and realized there was some very old produce on top of the fridge, hiding behind a bunch of boxes.  He tossed it out, and the fruit flies disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an enclosed porch, or open to the elements?

If it's enclosed, then you need to eliminate sources of damp - they won't breed near moving water, so the fountain is unlikely to be the source, unless there's a nice green mossy bit underneath.

House plants - they love damp potting compost, so you have to under-water your plants to kill them off, garbage bins, food recycle/composting, etc. Basically anything organic & damp.

If it's an open porch, they could be coming from literally anywhere nearby. Fly spray would be a constant task; traps would catch some, but would be unlikely to reduce apparent numbers, as new ones come to fill the gap left by the caught ones in a constant cycle.
You'd need to try growing something known to put insects off. Citrus & lavender tend to be unpopular with many insects, also a lot of highly scented herbs, but figuring out the exact plant/insect match may not be easy.
You'd have a nice herb garden though ;)

Here are some suggestions -
https://www.prevention.com/life/g32982866/plants-that-repel-bugs/
https://www.thespruce.com/plants-that-repel-insects-4142012